# How do I find the $\theta$ in this isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqRyo.jpg) to the image of the isosceles triangle.
For a description of the image:
$\overline{AB}=\overline{AC}=\overline{BD}$
$\overline{CD}=\overline{CE}$
$B,C,D$ are collinear
$A,C,E$ are collinear
$\angle{ABE}=50^{\circ}$
$\theta=\angle{BAC}=$?

Comment: Try drawing the lines $AD$ and $DE$. They might help.

Comment: Are $A, C$ and $E$ collinear?

Comment: (Useless) Fact: $\theta > 80$. Another one: $BC = AE$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $AC=y$ and $EC=x$.

Hence, from $\Delta ABC$ we obtain $$\sin\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{x+y}{2y}$$ and by law of sines for $\Delta AEB$ we obtain
$$\frac{y}{\sin(50^{\circ}+\theta)}=\frac{x+y}{\sin50^{\circ}},$$ which gives
$$2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\sin(50^{\circ}+\theta)=\sin50^{\circ},$$ which gives $$\theta=100^{\circ}.$$

Comment: How do I solve that last equation ($2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\sin(50^{\circ}+\theta)=\sin50^{\circ}$)?

Comment: I remember that it was calculus. I'll try to restore.